# How to upload local files to Firebase storage from Jupyter Notebook using Python

Tags: python, api, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Since I guess importing google.cloud.storage might be a very first step to set API connecting the firebase storage, what I did first is to install google-cloud on Ubuntu like this:

```
$ pip install --upgrade google-cloud
```

and it told me:

> Successfully installed google-cloud

Then I tried to import storage from google.could on Jupyter Notebook like:

```
from google.cloud import storage
```

but it gave me an error message, says:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

so I am wondering what are the necessary steps to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage` as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python). It should be included in `google-cloud` library anyway, so most likely there is some kind of issue related to the Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: As you said, I feel like it's a common problem in Jupyter Notebook that a certain installed module could not be found.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do two steps which may resolve this issue.

1. Check from where google package comes
2. Try to install google package in virtualenv