# How to display the output of .ipynb file in a webpage?

Tags: html, reactjs, jupyter-notebook

I'm a bit confused as to how I should go about with my problem. I have some lines of code in a .ipynb file (Jupyter notebook). I have created a basic front end using ReactJS. Now, I wish to display the output of any specific part of the code written in the .ipynb file, onto my webpage. How would I do this? Would I have to use API calls to call a particular function in my .ipynb file? Or if not, would anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I have not worked with python framework. But if the output that you have is stored in a database you can create a small node app to serve through an API.

Or you can serve your data on Firebase it will create hit that API and use the result in your React App.

Here is a question on uploading local files on firebase [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51739565/how-to-upload-local-files-to-firebase-storage-from-jupyter-notebook-using-python)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Well nope, my output is not stored in a database. So I'm quite lost and don't know how I could go about this.